# HiveError: There is already a TypeAdapter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm currently implementing `Hive` in my FlutterApp. Unfortunately this error pops up all the time:

> HiveError: There is already a TypeAdapter for typeId 100.

This is my object:

```
@HiveType(typeId: 100)
class ShopList{
  @HiveField(0)
  String name;
  @HiveField(1)
  List<ListProduct> products = List();

  ShopList({this.name, this.products});
```

That's the AUTO-GENERATED adapter:

```
class ShopListAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ShopList> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 100;

  @override
  ShopList read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return ShopList(
      name: fields[0] as String,
      products: (fields[1] as List)?.cast<ListProduct>(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, ShopList obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.name)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.products);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ShopListAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

I have some other Objects with the `typeId`s 101 and 102, which throw the same error.
The `Hive.registerAdapter(ShopListAdapter));` runs in a `try-catch-block`. So if the adapter were already loaded, the code can just go on, BUT the `FutureBuilder`-Widget using the value from the `Hive` loads infinitely long.
Do you have any tips?

Comment: I got the same problem, as this is my first time using hive, waiting some one to give the answer, thanks

Comment: Same problem here!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was using an UserAdapter type `id=0` so you should check before calling the `Hive.registerAdapter` as i showed you the below code

[image]

```
 if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(0)) {
      Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to check typeId, they should be different and unique from other class models even in same file.

```
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Module1 {}

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Module2 {}
```

Once typeId has been changed then

```
reinstall the app,
delete .g.dart generated file,
run command ---> flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Comment: It is the same as above though, I run this command to recreate a ".g.dart" file. `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Comment: yes, --delete-conflicting-outputs, till work as wll

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have registered the adapter, then that must be cache issue, run flutter clean and **MOST IMPORTANTLY** Unstill the app and run it afresh. The problem will be so

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that each Hive class has a unique **typeId** value. The **@HiveType(typeId: 0)** annotation is used to specify a unique type identifier for a class in Hive. If you have multiple classes, make sure that the **typeId** values are distinct for each class. For example, you can use **@HiveType(typeId: 1)** for one class, **@HiveType(typeId: 2)** for another, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Friend, I used the command Hive.resetAdapters() , it worked for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQRSQ.png)

Comment: WARNING: This method is only intended to be used for integration and unit tests
and SHOULD not be used in production code.